# How to get jQuery to see .clone() elements?

Tags: jquery

Apologies for the newbishness of my question, I'm still new to jQuery. I've hit a problem: Is there a way to get jQuery to be able to see and react to elements dynamically created with `.clone()`?

At the moment, whenever I clone something it apparently isn't "seen" by the DOM, and so events are not registered.

Here's a messy jsFiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/3MvPL/

Clicking "submit" brings up the `alert()`, but a cloned version of the element doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `true` in clone arguments :

```
$(".newForm").clone(true).appendTo("#forms").removeClass("newForm").fadeIn();
```

jQuery clone : http://api.jquery.com/clone/

First argument is "cloning event handler".

Comment: And this is how clone should be used

Comment: @j08691 Minimal extra code? My answer only added one word ;) but you're correct in that this is probably the nicer way to do it.

Comment: @Zenith - no offense, your answer works as well. I just would use this solution myself over the event delegation method in this particular instance.

Comment: @Zenith mine add 4 characters, your is like 14! J/k both answer are good ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is because the element is dynamically appended:

```
$("#forms").on("submit", ".saveForm", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Worked!");
});
```

Take a look at the event delegation section of the documentation [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

[**jsFiddle example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3MvPL/1/)

Comment: This is the right answer: better to use delegation than to add cloned event handlers.

Comment: @Tallmaris Hmmm can you tell me why? ;)

Comment: Ok, maybe "better" is only my opinion but I see it more efficient to hook one event, with delegation, rather than hooking an event for each form. Moreover you need to remember to remove the event in case you do other manipulations, while with delegation you only have one event listening on the outer `div`.

Comment: @Tallmaris i understand it is your opinion, but delegated even are slower than direct binding. Also, it is not that hard to do `$('selector').off().remove()`. But as you said, personnal preference ;)